# Solution Checker In Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, solution, dynamics-365

I am trying to create a build pipeline inside our dynamics 365 organization.

While doing different research I came across a tool that is "Solution Checker" which traces the code and give an output based on CRM best practices.

I am currently working on On-Premises organization and while doing research I found that this tool is only available for online or CDS platform.

So, is there a way where I can have this to test my On-Premise organization.

In addition there is another tool called ODCA (On demand code analysis). I would also like to know what are the differences between these two tools.

And, last how can I achieve the build pipeline for Dynamics 365. Do I have to use Azure DevOps to achieve the build pipeline.

Note: I am using TFS as my source code repository.

Answer (score 1):

So, is there a way where I can have this to test my On-Premise organization.

No, Solution checker is available only online, it is a solution provided by Microsoft so that any development should follow standard.

ODCA (On demand code analysis)
If I remember correctly this solution is available as custom i.e it is created as Plugin(Add on) you can give it a try, I personally have not used anything like this OnPrem.

Now regarding CI/CD
This point is quite broad, We basically use Azure Devops (Git) as version control. We have Build pipeline built such as if we merge code to Develop branch automatic build will run and if plugin/web resource pass then email as success else failure email and fixing it before merging code.

It depends how you wish to achieve this. You will have to dig deep into Devops and build.